# Scrollbars in android

Tags: android, scrollview

Can any one tell me how i can set my scroll view with both vertical and horizontal scroll ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. `ScrollView` is vertical scroll. `HorizontalScrollView` is horizontal scroll.

Comment: Thanks for the idea..I just combined both....<HorizontalScrollView> <ScrollView> "Thanks" </ScrollView>  </HorizontalScrollView>

Answer (score 1):

The only `View` (in the SDK) that I know of that has both vertical and horizontal scroll is the [`WebView`](http://d.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html). See if you can work with that. If not, you'll have to create your own `View`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need both horizontal and vertical scrolling, you shouldn't be using ScrollViews. Instead, as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044775/scrollview-vertical-and-horizontal-in-android) question points out, you can use a combination of FrameLayouts and RelativeLayouts to achieve the desired effect.