# Show data In Gridview Format in android

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.1

I want to fetch data from database and show them in to android base mobile.
I have tried Gridview but with gridview bidirectional(Horizontal and vertical) scrollbar not possible either I cannot put.
So is there any option of gridview and I can show data like gridview or how can I put bidirectional scrollbar in gridview.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html), which allows you to layout the rows yourself, combined with a bidirectional scroller like the ones described in [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044775/scrollview-vertical-and-horizontal-in-android).