# How to implement scroll left-right,updown when we have a big image

Tags: android

When i get a bigger size bitmap image from server that takes double of width and height of my emulator screen. Now i want to see that image by scrolling the image up-down and also left-right to see full image.
Other option is to zoom-in the image.
please suggest answer for Both..i mean scroll view as well as zoom in..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had the same issue so i am displaying the image using WebView. I have searched a lot on the net but doesn't find better solution. If someone has please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044775/scrollview-vertical-and-horizontal-in-android) :

[Scrollview vertical and horizontal in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044775/scrollview-vertical-and-horizontal-in-android)

tested it myself and it works like a charm