# Scrolling after the end of animation, android

Tags: java, android, layout, animation

I have an array of views, seats in the cinema. I need to apply a set of animation (scale and translate) to them to make some kind of zoom. I apply animation to every view. Animation looks like this:

```java
    AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(context, null);

    float toXDelta = (place.getX() * 2) - place.getX();
    float toYDelta = (place.getY() * 2) - place.getY();
    Animation translate = new TranslateAnimation(0, toXDelta, 0, toYDelta);
    translate.setDuration(4000);
    translate.setFillAfter(true);
    translate.setFillEnabled(true);

    Animation scale = new ScaleAnimation(1, 5, 1, 5);
    scale.setDuration(4000);
    scale.setFillAfter(true);
    scale.setFillEnabled(true);

    set.addAnimation(translate);
    set.addAnimation(scale);

    set.setFillAfter(true);
    set.setAnimationListener(new KaroAnimationListener(this));

    animation = set;
```

So, my layout looks like this:

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:padding="10px">
<ScrollView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:id="@+id/vertical_scroll"
            android:fillViewport="true">
    <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/scrollable_places"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content">

        </RelativeLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>

<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/reserve_places_button"
        android:onClick="onReserveClick"
        android:layout_below="@id/vertical_scroll"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Bron!"/>
```

I put my views into `RelativeLayout` with id `scrollable_places`. So, after the end of animation some of this views go out of bounds of the screen, but there is no scroll available.
I guess that i need to redefine the `dimentions` of `RelativeLayout or other, parent, layouts`, but i don't know how to do it manually.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to post delay a scroll to this end of your ScrollView like this :

```
scrollView.postDelayed( new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    scrollView.fullScroll( View.FOCUS_DOWN);
                }
            }, 4300);
```

So that it fits to start after the end of your animation or you could do this after you listened to the end of your animation with an [AnimationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html) and in this case you could use a smaller delay than 4300 ms, something around 300 would do.

Regards,
 Stéphane

Comment: thanks! It works fine with ScrollView, but if i want do the same trick with HorizontalScrollView (that have ScrollView as a parent in my layout) just replaced View.FOCUS_DOWN by View.FOCUS_RIGHT, this isn't working. Maybe something wrong with my layout?

Comment: You should also have a look here for your layout question. This thread is about horizontal and vertical scrolling.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044775/scrollview-vertical-and-horizontal-in-android