# android - can't make my table scroll horizontally

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to make a horizontally scrollable table in android. When I enter data that exceeds the screen size the scroll bar doesn't appear. I tried all sorts of stuff (with / without the LinearLayout as a child of the HorizontalScrollView, all sorts of options for the controls width). Nothing works. Help, please.

This is my config:

```
  <HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:text="@string/passphrase" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/passphraseSpinner"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:text="@string/configuration" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/configurationSpinner"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:text="@string/speaker" />


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editSpeaker"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:imeOptions="actionGo"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="@string/defaultSpeaker" />

            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer [Scrollview vertical and horizontal in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044775/scrollview-vertical-and-horizontal-in-android) lead me to: http://android-code-crumbs.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-set-horizontal-and-vertical.html#more

which gave me this, I hope this helps:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="title:" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical" >

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/horizontalView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical" >

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="3dp"
                        android:text="sdf" />

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/passphraseSpinner"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="3dp"
                        android:text="sdfsdf" />

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/configurationSpinner"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <HorizontalScrollView
                        android:id="@+id/hs"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView3"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:padding="3dp"
                            android:text="sdasdjsaljdjhdlksajhdlksajhdlkjsahdlksajhdlfsd" />
                    </HorizontalScrollView>

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editSpeaker"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:imeOptions="actionGo"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="sdf" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: For a permanent scrollbar, try adding the following to the above: android:scrollbars="horizontal" android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true" android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0"

Comment: My above comment didn't produce a consistent result. I changed android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0" to android:scrollbarFadeDuration="-1" which at the time of this comment is showing a permanent scrollbar with no errors or complaints.