# Android: Drawing on Canvas in Scrollview

Tags: android, scrollview, drawing2d

I'm pretty much new in programing for Android. My app is sample app from api demos on developer android website. When I change parameters in that sample drawing it gets larger . That drawing needs to be displayed in scroll view (it doesn't need to be shrinked to fit the screen). This is the code I used:

**DrawPoints.java**

```
    public class DrawPoints extends myActivity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.routes); 

    }

    public static class SampleView extends View {
        private Paint   mPaint = new Paint();
        private float[] mPts;

       /*here comes declaration of parametars



        private void buildPoints() {

        /*here comes some coding*/

            }
        }

        public SampleView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeset) {
            super(context, attributeSet);

            buildPoints();
        }

        @Override 
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            Paint paint = mPaint;

            //here also comes code
        }
    }
}
```

here is xml Code:

**routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        <HorizontalScrollView 
                android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                    <!-- This code is just to make sure that scroll views work how 
                        I want them to work, image size is 625*351 px
                     <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image_View1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:src="@drawable/bus_design"
                            /> -->
                     <my.package.DrawPoints.SampleView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent" /> 


        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </ScrollView>
```

When I run that application and push the button in main activity application crashes. 
Drawing looks like Figure1 when I'm not using xml layout or scrollviews:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/za5MP.png
         **Figure1**

I also tried to use this code after method setContentView:

```
View v = new SampleView(this);
addContentView(v, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

and also this one:

```
View v = new SampleView(this);
    ScrollView.LayoutParams lp = new ScrollView.LayoutParams(1000, 1000);

    addContentView(v, lp);
```

when I use codes, shown above, app displays Figure1 without scrollview, it seems like second content view overwrites that xml but it doesn't show correctly. 
After that I tried to use this code after setContentView:

```
View v = new SampleView(this);
    FrameLayout fl = new FrameLayout(this);
    fl.findViewById(R.id.FrameLayout1);
    fl.addView(v);
```

Frame layout (FrameLayout1) is added in routes.xml file after horizontal scroll view. When application runs I get blank screen without Figure1.
Does Anyone have an idea how to upgrade my code that would display Figure1 in ScrollView?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello everyone, no one posted any answer on my question so I looked for some solutions. I found that in android is not implemented bi directional Scrolling 
I found really good implementation of bi directional scrolling on this web page [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044775/scrollview-vertical-and-horizontal-in-android
solution was posted by Mahdi Hijazi. Solution works like charm, but when I try to implement my SampleView class on his solution again nothing happens. If I got some solution I will than post that solution here. Until then hope that someone have solution.

Answer (score 12):

write this line in your touchevent of custom View class

getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)

Comment: That is so awsome :) best solution by far thanks!

I just call this on the `ScrollView` parent.

Answer (score 5):

finally I found solution to my problem. I used solution from this site:

[Link1](http://blog.gorges.us/wp-content/uploads/TwoDScrollView.java)

well I saw that solution before, but unfortunately I didn't realize that this solution is good for me. I knew that I need onMeasure method for Canvas to show it in xml, but withouth of solution from mentioned site it didn't work. Now it works. Here is my xml, and SampleView solution.

**XML code:**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/app_layout" android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <!-- SCENE -->
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scene_layout" 
        android:drawingCacheQuality="low"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <com.testiranje.Kristijan.TwoDScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scene_scroller" android:drawingCacheQuality="low"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal"

            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/scene_container" 
                android:drawingCacheQuality="low"
                android:background="@drawable/map"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <com.testiranje.Kristijan.SampleView
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

                    </com.testiranje.Kristijan.SampleView>

                <!--  <ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/scene_background" android:drawingCacheQuality="low"
                    android:background="@drawable/map"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" /> -->
            </RelativeLayout>
        </com.testiranje.Kristijan.TwoDScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**This is my SampleView solution:**

```
 public class SampleView extends View {
    private Paint   mPaint = new Paint();
    private float[] mPts;

    private static final float SIZE = 1000;
    private static final int SEGS = 50;
    private static final int X = 0;
    private static final int Y = 1;

    private void buildPoints() {
        final int ptCount = (SEGS + 1) * 2;
        mPts = new float[ptCount * 2];

        float value = 0;
        final float delta = SIZE / SEGS;
        for (int i = 0; i <= SEGS; i++) {
            mPts[i*4 + X] = SIZE - value;
            mPts[i*4 + Y] = 0;
            mPts[i*4 + X + 2] = 0;
            mPts[i*4 + Y + 2] = value;
            value += delta;
        }
    }

    public SampleView(Context context){
        super(context);
        //initSampleView();
        buildPoints();

    }

   //This constructor is very important because withouth of this 
   //you can't insert this view in xml
   public SampleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        //initSampleView();
        buildPoints();
    }

    /*private final void initSampleView() {
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);
    }*/

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        setMeasuredDimension(measureWidth(widthMeasureSpec),
                measureHeight(heightMeasureSpec));
    }

    /**
     * Determines the width of this view
     * @param measureSpec A measureSpec packed into an int
     * @return The width of the view, honoring constraints from measureSpec
     */
    private int measureWidth(int measureSpec) {
        int result = 0;
        //This is because of background image in relativeLayout, which is 1000*1000px
        measureSpec = 1001;
        int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
        int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);

        if (specMode == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED) {
            // We were told how big to be
            result = specSize;
        }

        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Determines the height of this view
     * @param measureSpec A measureSpec packed into an int
     * @return The height of the view, honoring constraints from measureSpec
     */
   private int measureHeight(int measureSpec) {
        int result = 0;
        //This is because of background image in relativeLayout, which is 1000*1000px 
        measureSpec = 1001;
        int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
        int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);


        if (specMode == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED) {
            // Here we say how Heigh to be
            result = specSize;
        } 
        return result;
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Paint paint = mPaint;

        canvas.translate(10, 10);

        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(0);
        canvas.drawLines(mPts, paint);


        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        canvas.drawPoints(mPts, paint);

    }
}
```

Now I got this image, when I run my app:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWhvT.png

If anyone have questions about this feel free to ask me :).

Comment: how to add a scroll on canvas?