# Android canvas drawing not visible

Tags: android, android-canvas, ondraw

If i use the ImageView , i can see the image on my activity , however i can't see when i draw it with a canvas. am i missing something ?. The drawable has the dimensions 479px*100px. I can see onDraw function is being called using a breakpoint inside it.

```
public View getScrollingImage(){
    View temp = new View(this){
        BitmapDrawable cloud=  (BitmapDrawable) MainActivity.this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cartoon_clouds);
        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            canvas.drawBitmap(cloud.getBitmap(), 0,0, null);
            invalidate();
        }
    };
    //ImageView temp = new ImageView(this);
    //temp.setImageDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cartoon_clouds));
    temp.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,1.0f));

    return temp;
}
```

adding it to view by ,

```
mainLayout.addView(getScrollingImage());
```

I am on Android 4.0.4.

Answer (score 3):

Got this working by overriding the onMeasure function in view , got this from [Android: Drawing on Canvas in Scrollview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303678/android-drawing-on-canvas-in-scrollview)
Thanks stackOverflow.

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    setMeasuredDimension(cloud.getBitmap().getWidth(),
            cloud.getBitmap().getHeight());
}
```