# ScrollView Horizontal in UI Programmatically Android

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I'm making a display in android programmatically and I  need scrollview horizontally and vertically. Have been work vertically, but still  not  work horizontally.

here the code :

```
    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(FILL_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT);
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(VERTICAL); 

    linearLayout.addView(tableLayout(count));
    linearLayout.addView(submitButton());
    sv.addView(linearLayout);
    setContentView(sv);
```

Please help me to make it work horizontally.

Thankyou :)

Comment: take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044775/scrollview-vertical-and-horizontal-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [HorizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html) if you want horizontal scrolling. You cannot do both horizontal and vertical at the same time though, in that case you'll probably have to write a custom view.

Comment: Would you explain more detail about costum view ?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

Answer (score 1):

```
HorizontalScrollView sv = new HorizontalScrollView(this);
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
```