# How to avoid the Input Method hiding the EditText and Button at the bottom of a WebView

Tags: android, webview, android-input-method

I load a web page by using `WebView` in my app and there are `EditText` and `Button` at the bottom of the page. When I press the `EditText`, the soft input method will show, but the input method hides the `EditText` and `Button`.

I want the `EditText` and `Button` move to the top of the input method, so the input method won't hide them.

I added the `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` to my activity tag in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, but it didn't work.

What else can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using adjustPan property,Try using following property.It works fine for me..

```
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Comment: Yes, this is really what I want.By adding the property above to my activity tag in the AndroidManifest.xml, the webview will move upwards enough to show even its bottom when the soft keyboard appears.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your webview in ScrollView layout. Once keyboad will appear the scroll layout will move upwards. Remember you can have only one child in ScrollView layout. Better put some Layout like Linear or Relative in Scrollview then add other child views in that layout.

Take a look at these:

[Scrollview vertical and horizontal in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044775/scrollview-vertical-and-horizontal-in-android)

http://www.androidaspect.com/2012/02/scrollview-tutorial-android-ui.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After I putting my webview in a ScrollView layout, when the keyboard appear, the csroll layout move upwards to reveal the EditText which is focused. But it did't move enough to reveal all the EditText and Bttons. Is there a way to force the scroll layout to move upwards enough to show even the bottom of the webview?

Comment: Catch keyboard pop up event and then scroll the scroll view to top manually