# Horizontal and vertical scroll view at runtime

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I want to add horizontal and vertical scroll view in my Android application at runtime.

```
ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.opsbuds);
ll.setLayoutParams (new LayoutParams 
        (LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.setMargins(40, 20, 0, 0);
sv.addView(ll);
```

now my code is like this, but it is not working properly

```
ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
HorizontalScrollView horizontal = new HorizontalScrollView(this);
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.opsbuds);
ll.setLayoutParams (new LayoutParams 
        (LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.setMargins(40, 20, 0, 0);
horizontal.addView(ll);
```

by using above code I can add vertical scroll view. but when I use both horizontal ans vertical it is not coming properly...

Comment: so far i am able to add veritcal scrollview at runtime but i want both horizontal and vertical

Comment: You can implement a `HorizontalScrollView` in the same way as a `ScrollView`. What part of this are you struggling with? Do you want both vertical *and* horizontal scrolling for the same `View`?

Comment: yeah.. i should be able to scroll vertically and horizontally also.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scrollview vertical and horizontal in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044775/scrollview-vertical-and-horizontal-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You need a layout in your ScrollView.  It doesn't especially matter what that layout is, but I like to use RelativeLayouts.  Your ScrollView should have only a layout child, and that layout should have a HorizontalScrollView child.