# Android: Horizontal list view in vertical scroll view?

Tags: android, scrollview, horizontal-scrolling

I want to make the same implementation a [pulse application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alphonso.pulse&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5hbHBob25zby5wdWxzZSJd).

Horizontal list view inside a vertical list view.

[image]

i tried this [project](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34) for horizontal  list view, but when i am trying to scroll horizontal the vertical scroll active and the list is goes up and down.
how can i prevent this issues.

Comment: Hey, have you found a solution to this problem? I'm implementing almost the exact same thing and I'm having the same issue.

Comment: This is what you are looking for : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646028/android-horizontalscrollview-within-scrollview-touch-handling

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24107433/view-pager-in-listview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be much easier if you paste your piece of code with your question, allowing to see why it goes wrong. My best guess without this information is to check you usage of `fill_parent` vs `wrap_content`.

Answer (score 22):

it's work on my app...

just like pulse app... horizontallistview inside vertical listview

**this is the solution...**

just put this code in u'r onscroll of HorizontalListview class...

```
ViewParent viewParent = getParent();

if (viewParent != null) {

    viewParent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

}
```

Comment: I have horizontal listview in vertical listview. And this one works good with mine as well.

Answer (score -1):

i think you should use some horizontal scrollviews in a vertical scrollview. and in each horizontal scrollview, you can give listview, gridview, etc... if you want. I think it's better solution for this problem. :)

Comment: I am using Vertical scroll view with four horizontal list view.

Comment: ya. you can replace horizontal listview by horizontal scroll view, and in each horizontal scroll view, you can put horizontal list view to that.