# How Pulse news apps implement the horizontal scroll view with vertical scroll or in list view in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I would like to develop a similar UI implementation to the Pulse app on Android. There is no native Android component available for horizontal scroll view with adapters or lazy loading.

How did they make this UI?

Comment: cek this out..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775677/android-horizontal-list-view-in-vertical-scroll-view/17382886#17382886

i think this is the solution...

Answer (score 2):

i don't know how the Pulse app does it, but maybe you could try to make do with a `Horizontal Listview` here: http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I want exact way how they did do you have any idea?

Comment: Well I can't know unless it's open source or I was on the development team, but you should be able to get very close with a horizontal listview and listview principles

Comment: can't we use gallery view horizontally and and in vertical scroll view pls advise me here is it good approch or not?

Comment: you can do in that way but gallery has center locking mechanism.