# How to automatically scroll horizontal scrollview in android

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I have five images in a horizontal scroll view and I want to scroll these images automatically from left to right and right to left when the page load is done.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scrollview vertical and horizontal in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044775/scrollview-vertical-and-horizontal-in-android)

Comment: @martinclayton Did you link to the right question? I don't think the author wants to scroll vertically and horizontally... I think they want a layout that changes images on an interval, much like http://developer.android.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer this project [link...](https://github.com/blessenm/SlideshowDemo) hope this solves your problem ...

Answer (score 0):

Insert a HorizontalScrollView tag indise your ScrollView tag in XML file

**For Ex:**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:scrollbars="vertical">

<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="320px" android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linlay" android:layout_width="320px"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:stretchColumns="1"
        android:background="#000000"/>

</HorizontalScrollView>

</ScrollView>
```