# Android Scroll View move horizontal and vertical at same time?

Tags: android, layout, view

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Scrollview vertical and horizontal in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044775/scrollview-vertical-and-horizontal-in-android)

I want to find a view that can scroll vertically and horizontally. Because i have the following issue. I want to move the viewport around the actual view size. Do anyone know how to solve it??

```
    Actual view size
----------------------------        
|            |             |
|            |             |
|  Viewport  |             |
|            |             |
|            |             |
|-------------             |
|                          |
|                          |
|---------------------------
```

Thanks.

Comment: This is discussed in great detail here: [Scrollview vertical and horizontal in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044775/scrollview-vertical-and-horizontal-in-android)