# Table - Conflict onTouchEvent and OnClickListener

Tags: android, scroll, onclicklistener, touch-event, android-tablelayout

I have a TableLayout with a HScroll and VScroll so I can scroll in all directions. For this scrollable layout I used: [Scrollview vertical and horizontal in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044775/scrollview-vertical-and-horizontal-in-android) . This uses a onTouchEvent.

There are items in my TableLayout with a onClickListener.

When i Scroll in the Table and touch an item with a onClickListener the scrolling is not working. When I just click on the item the onClickListener works fine. But I also want to scroll over these items when a move gesture is used.

How can I solve this conflict between onTouchEvent and onClickListener?

This is my onTouchEvent:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if(true) {
                mx = event.getX();
                my = event.getY();
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if(true) {
                curX = event.getX();
                curY = event.getY();
                vScroll.scrollBy((int) (mx - curX), (int) (my - curY));
                hScroll.scrollBy((int) (mx - curX), (int) (my - curY));
                mx = curX;
                my = curY;
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if(true) {
                curX = event.getX();
                curY = event.getY();
                vScroll.scrollBy((int) (mx - curX), (int) (my - curY));
                hScroll.scrollBy((int) (mx - curX), (int) (my - curY));
            }
            break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try simply returning false from onTouchEvent method, so that you indicate the android system that you didn't consume the event and it should continue passing it through...