# Not able to move vertically when using a map inside Scrollview

Tags: android, dictionary, scrollview

In my android app I am not able to move vertically when I put a map inside a Scrollview and if I am using other layouts then the items at the bottom are not visible.I had seen all the solutions provided before my question but couldn't found any appropriate solution..Thanks in advance if anybody could be able provide me solution who to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Scroll view by default only scrolls vertically. [Have a look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5224088/2558344), it might solve your problem.