# Scrolling an image in android

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-scrollview

I have an image in my application. But size of the image becomes larger for smaller screens. So I tried by adding scroll view for the image.

Code:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbarFadeDuration="10"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image"
    android:layout_marginLeft="160dp"
    android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="@id/imageView1"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@id/imageView1"
    android:src="@drawable/abc" />

</ScrollView>
```

But this allows me to scroll in vertical direction only. Help me what do so that I can scroll the image in horizontal direction also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution might be to scale the image to fit the the screen using [scaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html). To include horizontal/vertical scrolling, take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6716638/905349).

Comment: used scaleType but still I cannot scroll it horizontal

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TouchImageView](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView). This project adds touch functionality to android imageView. Scroll, pinchzoom etc.