# Vertical, Horizontal and Diagonal Scrolling in Android

Tags: android, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

I am sort of a beginner in android and I want to create a sort of 'board game'. This board game need a... well... board, and I know it's gonna be bigger than the screen in some device. So, any way to 'move around' the map/board in a way a bit like how google maps is able to move around? I know I can't put a HorizontalScrollView in a VerticalScrollView from my research or anything like that, because it doesn't allow diagonal scrolling and bugs out some times...

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Funny how Google never shows the good answers...
And why does he make MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN do nothing?

Comment: See the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044775/scrollview-vertical-and-horizontal-in-android)

Comment: Did you check the link????

Comment: I did, im looking through and been confused.

Comment: I think this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6235806/3168859) would help you..

Comment: "And why does he make MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN do nothing?" I said before. That's why im confused. Thanks for all your efforts, though!

Comment: Are you still into this?

Comment: Hm? Well... yes... but I'm looking into OpenGL and other stuff like it, instead of purely building it out of tables and ImageButtons.