# Prevent ImageView from receiving touch events when scrolling

Tags: android, event-handling, scroll, imageview

I'm making an app with lots of `ImageView`s and I needed to attach a touch listener in some of them. While doing this, I encountered a problem. If the pointer was held down at the location where the `ImageView` with touch listeners attached to it and was about to produce a scrolling event, there seems a fighting scene between the `View`s and the `ScrollView` in w/c where the event was actually occured and in w/c the event is supposed to belong. The **screen scrolls in a fast rate** then return where the first pointer was touched down, so it means it is an unwanted behavior.

Setting an `onTouchListener` in the `ImageView` makes the scrolling uneasy and unwanted, how do I prevent `ImageView` from receiving touch events when scrolling?

---

### Some of the codes

**Layout**: *act_map_view.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<com.nkraft.mobiletomblocator.CustomVScroll
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/vScroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    <com.nkraft.mobiletomblocator.CustomHScroll 
        android:id="@+id/hScroll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

            <com.nkraft.mobiletomblocator.CustomGridLayout
                android:id="@+id/map_grid"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            </com.nkraft.mobiletomblocator.CustomGridLayout>

    </com.nkraft.mobiletomblocator.CustomHScroll>

</com.nkraft.mobiletomblocator.CustomVScroll>
```

**Notes:**

- The `GridLayout` is populated with `ImageView`s at runtime.
- I customized my horizontal and vertical `ScrollView` so that I can scroll in both directions concurrently i.e diagonal scrolling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the notes I've mention, I figured a clue from the problem I'm currently facing. I think this issue had been thought before the standard android's scrollbar was implemented. The main reason this occurs to me is that I extended the class of the scrollbars and totally replacing the default behavior of it. So for me to achieve what I want (the scrollbar with diagonal scrolling) I follow this [post](http://web.archive.org/web/20131020193237/http://blog.gorges.us/2010/06/android-two-dimensional-scrollview) and replace both my vertical and horizontal scrollview with this `TwoDScrollView`, also thanks for this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044775/scrollview-vertical-and-horizontal-in-android#answer-5224088) directing me to it.