# Multi scroll android (horizontal, vertical, diagonal)

Tags: java, android, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

I wold like to implement in my app a multiscroll (horizontal, vertical, diagonal).

Can you help me with some example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scrollview vertical and horizontal in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044775/scrollview-vertical-and-horizontal-in-android)

Comment: doesn't help me. i've already read it