# Scrollview jumps/repositions when trying to scroll on a clickable child of it

Tags: android, scrollview, onclicklistener

I am using two (embedded) `ScrollViews` like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044775/scrollview-vertical-and-horizontal-in-android), in order to create a '2D `Scrollview`'.

I add multiple childs to this view, and to some of them I set `OnClickListener` (I also tried with `OnLongClickListener` as well).

Functionally the result is what I have expected, although if I try to scroll (starting from a child, that has either of the listeners), the scrollview jumps/repositions to the ~opposite direction, I started the scroll to. So if I scroll like this e.g. upwards, the view jumps a big downwards so that I can scroll up at most to the original position.

I have been trying to play around with calling `setFocusable(false)` on the childs and `setFocusable(true)` on the `ScrollView(s)` (but also tried different permutations of it, as I am not sure about `setFocusable()`), but couldn't really get on top of it.. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Just encase you are still wondering this is happening because when you start scrolling the other scroll view, ACTION_CANCEL is posted to the on touch method of the original ScrollView which causes a default scroll view to jump back to its original position.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, and thanks for your comment. 
Now as I came back to this question, I debugged the scrollviews in question, but ACTION_CANCEL is never posted. Instead ACTION_MASK is posted first (two times), and than ACTION_UP.
Any ideas?