# android -How to stop stretching background image on linearlayout

Tags: android

I've set an image as background on a linearlayout . This is the code :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/mainbg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp"
    >
```

The problem is , the width of the image is about 2000px , I don't want to scale down the with to fit the screen , I just want to show as much as it take as background and not strech it .

how can I do so ?

thanks

Comment: take one imageview and use scaletype of imageview

Answer (score 7):

add an image view in your layout and set its scaletype to centerCrop

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/mainbg" />

</LinearLayout>
```

check image scale types:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Answer (score 5):

You can use RelativeLayout and put ImageView with scaleType inside it and LinearLayout having all your content.

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:src="@drawable/mainbg"
   android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

  <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:padding="5dp">

    -----Your Content----

  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This answer works for me, just be careful with the L letter in the middle of  Relativelayout closing tag needs to be capital L.

Answer (score 0):

You can do things in two way...

1. Fit the full image (without cropping/leaving portion of photo).
   Use Vertical ScrollView + Horizontal ScrollView combined and use you layout as first child.

   ```
   <ScrollView
       android:id="@+id/scrollView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"></ScrollView>
   <HorizontalScrollView
       android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@drawable/a"
       android:orientation="vertical">
   </LinearLayout>
   ```
2. You can use custom view

customScrollView

```
package com.scrollable.view;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

public class VScroll extends ScrollView {

    public VScroll(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public VScroll(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public VScroll(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And you can refer [Scrollview vertical and horizontal in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044775/scrollview-vertical-and-horizontal-in-android)...