# Pan-able Layout (needs a little fix to work)

Tags: android, scroll, scrollview, pan, bidirectional

I am trying to make a **panable linear layout**. Here is a part of the code from best answer of [How can I make my layout scroll both horizontally and vertically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044775/scrollview-vertical-and-horizontal-in-android) tread. Everything works on first touch and drag cycle, but on second drag, layout **position resetting** to first position. So overall position does not changing. The reason is intercepting ACTION_DOWN event by scrollView. How to fix it?

```
 @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        switch (event.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                lastX = event.getX();
                lastY = event.getY();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                curX = event.getX();
                curY = event.getY();
                vScroll.scrollBy((int) (lastX - curX), (int) (lastY - curY));
                hScroll.scrollBy((int) (lastX - curX), (int) (lastY - curY));
                lastX = curX;
                lastY = curY;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                curX = event.getX();
                curY = event.getY();
                vScroll.scrollBy((int) (lastX - curX), (int) (lastY - curY));
                hScroll.scrollBy((int) (lastX - curX), (int) (lastY - curY));
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Differently from original, I just changed variable names and moved declaration to top of code.

(Sorry if any language mistakes, English is not my native one)