# Scrollview does not scroll

Tags: android, scrollview

The `ScrollView` in the layout has three `Imageviews` which has drawable images set as its background.The dimensions of `ImageViews` are 150dp. I have set the height of the ScrollView to `wrap_content` and `scrollbars` attribute to `horizontal`.But it does not scroll.Please help me with the problem.

Code:

```
<ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/offerscroll"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@+id/offr_prsnl_chs_pht"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/prsnl_img_dimen"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/prsnl_img_dimen"
                    android:id="@+id/offr_img1"
                    android:background="@drawable/ambulance"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/prsnl_img_dimen"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/prsnl_img_dimen"
                    android:id="@+id/offr_img2"
                    android:background="@drawable/ambulance"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/prsnl_img_dimen"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/prsnl_img_dimen"
                    android:id="@+id/offr_img3"
                    android:background="@drawable/ambulance"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Maybe u'r finding this :
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044775/scrollview-vertical-and-horizontal-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044775/scrollview-vertical-and-horizontal-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

why not using a `HorizontalScrollView` instead

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/offerscroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:measureAllChildren="false"
    android:layout_below="@+id/offr_prsnl_chs_pht"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal" >


    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `HorizontalScrollView` . It should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

As far as your code goes there is no problem so there can be a possibility:

Size of images(dimen values) satisfy the layout size i.e. no scrolling might be needed.

See if changing that works for you.