# Making Both Horizontal and Vertical ScrollableLayout

Tags: android, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

I am trying to make both horizantally and vertically `ScrollableLayout`. I managed to make horizantally or vertically scrollable layout but I couldn't make it for both side.

I tried to put `ScrollView` inside `HorizontalScrollView` but when I do that it shrinked horizontal side. Here is my code:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    </ScrollView>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

I am adding my views inside `ScrollView` with java code.

Comment: see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044775/scrollview-vertical-and-horizontal-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is nothing in the standard library that does what you want. Since you said in a comment somewhere on this page that you are going to put a TableLayout inside, you'll probably be better served by some third-party component such as [TableFixHeaders](https://github.com/celerysoft/TableFixHeaders).

Answer (score 0):

This code actually worked for me:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/verticalScroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        </HorizontalScrollView>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```