# ScrollView Inside ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview

I Know people from Google have asked us not to put Scrollable view inside another Scrollable view but is there any official statement from them directing us not to do so?

Comment: Thank you for your responses but it is a requirement in the app I am working... :( ... Tried loads of stuff from overriding the touch events to creating a custom scroll view but none seems to work. Need an official Documentation so that I can explain it to my superiors.

Comment: blindstuff have you checked an iPhone?, when you have by example a ListView, inside a Scroll you can scroll them both depending of the focus, or the position...

Comment: are you sure there is another ScrollView behind the ListView? The ListView is able to scroll by itself

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490821/scrollview-inside-scrollview/11554823#11554823

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Is this close enough?

> You should never use a
>   HorizontalScrollView with a ListView,
>   since ListView takes care of its own
>   scrolling. Most importantly, doing
>   this defeats all of the important
>   optimizations in ListView for dealing
>   with large lists, since it effectively
>   forces the ListView to display its
>   entire list of items to fill up the
>   infinite container supplied by
>   HorizontalScrollView.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html

UPDATE:

Since you may be forced to use a two dimensional scrollview, you may consider using this:
[**Internet archive** of blog.gorges.us/2010/06/android-two-dimensional-scrollview/](https://web.archive.org/web/20130305091318/http://blog.gorges.us/2010/06/android-two-dimensional-scrollview)

I haven't used this but it may be a reasonable approach.

Comment: Hi Pedro, First of all thank you for your response. my app contains a back ground image that requires a scrollview (as it is bigger than the screen) and that background image will contain another image that also requires a scrollview (as it is also bigger than the screen). So my need is to have a vertical scrollView inside a vertical Scrollview... Any ideas on that one will be really helpful?

Comment: have you tried to do that? you'll have to specify some height for the inner scrollview (say 200dip?) and the outer one should match parent's size (the whole screen, I guess). try it and use different background colors so you know what you're getting

Comment: I have tried it...When i try to scroll the inner scroll view the touch event is being passed to the outer scroll view even when i  override the inner's onTouch() to return true... So only the outer scroll view is scrollable.

Comment: We can use HorizontalScrollView with a ListView.It is possible and works fine in my case.Please check answer given by "Atul Bhardwaj" in this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210895/listview-inside-scrollview-is-not-scrolling-on-android)

Comment: Unfortunately, your Gorges blog link seems to be broken, the article might have been removed. Would you be able to find it back or suppress your broken link? Regards

Comment: internet archive to the rescue: https://web.archive.org/web/20130305091318/http://blog.gorges.us/2010/06/android-two-dimensional-scrollview (already updated the post)

Answer (score 66):

**Try this one**

**Note:** Here `parentScrollView` means Outer ScrollView   And `childScrollView` means Innner ScrollView

```
parentScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.v(TAG, "PARENT TOUCH");

        findViewById(R.id.child_scroll).getParent()
                .requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
        return false;
    }
});

childScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.v(TAG, "CHILD TOUCH");

        // Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of  child view
        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 Your approach works in most cases. Thanks but my question was for doc regards Android official statement.

Comment: I up voted your answer, but have a question. Why do you need to set the listener for the parent Scroll "findViewById(R.id.child_scroll). getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvents(false)" I have a non-scrollable TextView and a scrollable EditText inside a scrollview. I never want a touch event inside the EditText to go up to the parent, so once the EditText disallowInterceptTouchEvent is set to false, I never want it to change. Your code currently will never call the parentScrollView onTouch method unless the user is touching outside of the particular childView that was set to true.

Comment: continuing my comment above- Then once the user touches the particular childView, the childview requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent is set to true again. So, why set it to false at all?

Comment: I used an oversimplified version of your code for a NumberPicker nested in a ScrollView. It works, thank you :-)

Comment: Can somebody provide how the layout looks here ? I can not add more than one direct child to scrollview. The inside scrollview is not working for me.

Comment: @cppdev you can use like this <ScrollView>This is parent scrollview<LinearLayout><ScrollView>This is child scrollView</ScrollView></LinearLayout></ScrollView>

Answer (score 16):

[Atul Bhardwaj's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490821/scrollview-inside-scrollview/11554823#11554823) is the correct way to do it. But in case someone needs to apply it to a ScrollView where you have less control of the parent, I think this is flexible enough and just the way it's supposed to work:

```
private void makeMyScrollSmart() {
    myScroll.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View __v, MotionEvent __event) {
            if (__event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                //  Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of child view
                requestDisallowParentInterceptTouchEvent(__v, true);
            } else if (__event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || __event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                // Re-allows parent events
                requestDisallowParentInterceptTouchEvent(__v, false);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

private void requestDisallowParentInterceptTouchEvent(View __v, Boolean __disallowIntercept) {
    while (__v.getParent() != null && __v.getParent() instanceof View) {
        if (__v.getParent() instanceof ScrollView) {
            __v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(__disallowIntercept);
        }
        __v = (View) __v.getParent();
    }
}
```

What the function does is add a touch listener to `myScroll` that disables the parent's touch intercept when a touch starts in the child, and then enables it back when the touch actually ends. You don't need a reference to the parent `ScrollView` and it doesn't have to be the immediate parent... it'll travel the display list until it finds it.

Best of both worlds, in my opinion.

Comment: What's up with double-underscore names? Also, it'd make sense to locate the parent view once and keep a reference to it, as it probably never changes. And finally, some non-ScrollView widgets (like ViewPager) require same workaround.

Comment: Double-underscore is just a convention I use privately to keep track of method/function parameters; you can change it to whatever you want. I'm not using references in the above example to keep things simple & clean & safe (e.g. no references kept in memory). For non-ScrollView widgets, change the code to match whatever superclass you're using - the code above can work as a general idea of what to do.

Comment: what if i have a nested layout ?

Comment: requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean) method will recursively call upward by itself. Why you call requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(__disallowIntercept) upward again?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a possible solution. When reached the end of a child ScrollView it passes the control to the parent ScrollView to scroll. It works with ScrollView and ListView inside a ScrollView.

Step 1 - set the parent OnTouchListener

```
parentScroll.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Step 2 - set the childrens OnTouchListener (ScrollView or ListView)

```
aChildScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(shouldRequestDisallowIntercept((ViewGroup) v, event));
        return false;
    }
});
aListView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(shouldRequestDisallowIntercept((ViewGroup) v, event));
        return false;
    }
});
```

Step 3 - here are the required magic methods for the correct functionality

```
protected boolean shouldRequestDisallowIntercept(ViewGroup scrollView, MotionEvent event) {
    boolean disallowIntercept = true;
    float yOffset = getYOffset(event);

    if (scrollView instanceof ListView) {
        ListView listView = (ListView) scrollView;
        if (yOffset < 0 && listView.getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0 && listView.getChildAt(0).getTop() >= 0) {
            disallowIntercept = false;
        }
        else if (yOffset > 0 && listView.getLastVisiblePosition() == listView.getAdapter().getCount() - 1 && listView.getChildAt(listView.getChildCount() - 1).getBottom() <= listView.getHeight()) {
            disallowIntercept = false;
        }
    }
    else {
        float scrollY = scrollView.getScrollY();
        disallowIntercept = !((scrollY == 0 && yOffset < 0) || (scrollView.getHeight() + scrollY == scrollView.getChildAt(0).getHeight() && yOffset >= 0));

    }

    return disallowIntercept;
}

protected float getYOffset(MotionEvent ev) {
    final int historySize = ev.getHistorySize();
    final int pointerCount = ev.getPointerCount();

    if (historySize > 0 && pointerCount > 0) {
        float lastYOffset = ev.getHistoricalY(pointerCount - 1, historySize - 1);
        float currentYOffset = ev.getY(pointerCount - 1);

        float dY = lastYOffset - currentYOffset;

        return dY;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> *[...] is there any official statement from them directing us not to do so?*

I think there is though I can't seem to find it in my notes. I know I found such a statement when trying to have a scroll view in a list activity. I think there is actually a logical focus "bug" in the way the Android UI system deals with nested scrollables which probably should be better detected and communicated to the developer. But my advice is...

In the end it is better to consider a single scrollable view for the sake of the user anyway. It's like having scroll bars inside scroll bars on an HTML page; it may be legal but its a terrible user experience.

Comment: I've seen this alot in many iPhone apps and it's still user friendly.

Answer (score 2):

I found a very good solution. Please use this code.

```
    parentScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            Utils.showLog("PARENT TOUCH");
            findViewById(R.id.activity_mesh_child_scrollView).getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
            return false;
        }
    });

    childScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            Utils.showLog("CHILD TOUCH");
            // Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of child view
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

This will surely work. Please try and let me know if not working.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is an official statement about it, on a quite old video called "[**the world of ListView**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70)". They say not to put any scrollable view inside another one (when both are in the same direction).

However, now we have a new view that allows both views to scroll at the same time, probably to show a cool effect:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html

I didn't find any example for this, so what I wrote is just a guess of what it does and what it's used for.

Answer (score 1):

Android support v4 library has a class called NestedScrollView.

Try Nested Scroll View: http://ivankocijan.xyz/android-nestedscrollview/

Answer (score 0):

You can put a ScrollView inside another ScrollView. Just extend the child ScrollView to override the onTouchEvent method. Like so

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class ChildScrollView extends android.widget.ScrollView {
    private int parent_id;

    public ChildScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ChildScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ChildScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
        requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, i have created a sample project related to ScrollView inside a ScrollView. One View is Scrollable Both ways. Check It Out :-

**MainActivity.java -**

```
package com.example.dev_task_193_scrollview;

import com.example.dev_task_196_scrollview.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
    ImageView imageView1,imageView2,imageView3,IVimage1,IVimage2,IVimage3,IVimage4,IVimage5,IVimage6;
    ListView listView1,listView2;
    HorizontalScrollView horizontalScrollView1,horizontalScrollView2;
    ScrollView parentScrollView, scrollView1;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
                "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
                "Linux", "OS/2", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X", "Linux",
                "OS/2", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X", "Linux", "OS/2",
                "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobileWindowsMobileWindowsMobileWindowsMobile" };

        relativeLayout1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1);
        imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageView1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.info);

        imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        imageView2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.info);

        imageView3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        imageView3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.info);

        listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.list_item, values);
        listView1.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.list_item, values);
        listView2.setAdapter(adapter1);


        parentScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.parentScrollView);
        scrollView1 = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);


        horizontalScrollView1 = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView1);
        horizontalScrollView2 = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView2);


        IVimage1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage1);
        IVimage2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage2);
        IVimage3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage3);
        IVimage4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage4);
        IVimage5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage5);
        IVimage6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage6);


        scrollView1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                //  Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of child view
                parentScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                return false;
            }
        });

        horizontalScrollView1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                //  Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of child view
                parentScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                return false;
            }
        });
        listView1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                //  Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of child view
                parentScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                return false;
            }
        });
        listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked "+parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        });
        listView2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked "+parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        });

        listView2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                //  Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of child view
                parentScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                return false;
            }
        });
        horizontalScrollView2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                //  Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of child view
                parentScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                return false;
            }
        });
        /*imageView1.setOnClickListener(this);
        imageView2.setOnClickListener(this);
        imageView3.setOnClickListener(this);*/
        IVimage1.setOnClickListener(this);
        IVimage2.setOnClickListener(this);
        IVimage3.setOnClickListener(this);
        IVimage4.setOnClickListener(this);
        IVimage5.setOnClickListener(this);
        IVimage6.setOnClickListener(this);
        imageView1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                //  Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of child view
                parentScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked "+v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                return false;
            }
        });

        imageView2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                //  Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of child view
                parentScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked "+v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                return false;
            }
        });
        imageView3.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                //  Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of child view
                parentScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked "+v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                return false;
            }
        });

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.imageView1:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked "+v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.imageView2:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked "+v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.imageView3:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked "+v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.IVimage1:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked "+v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.IVimage2:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked "+v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.IVimage3:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked "+v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.IVimage4:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked "+v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.IVimage5:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked "+v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.IVimage6:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked "+v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;  




        }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml -**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/parentScrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/login_bg" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp" >

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:fillViewport="false" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                        android:layout_width="300dp"
                        android:layout_height="400dp"
                        android:tag="imageView1" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                        android:layout_width="300dp"
                        android:layout_height="400dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
                        android:tag="imageView2" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                        android:layout_width="300dp"
                        android:layout_height="400dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
                        android:tag="imageView3" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>
        </ScrollView>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="500dp"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcherwrweq" >
        </ListView>

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView2"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/claim_detail_header_bg"
            android:fillViewport="true" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/IVimage1"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="125dp"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/a"
                    android:tag="a" >
                </ImageView>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/IVimage2"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="125dp"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/b"
                    android:tag="b" >
                </ImageView>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/IVimage3"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="125dp"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/c"
                    android:tag="c" >
                </ImageView>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/IVimage4"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="125dp"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/g"
                    android:tag="g" >
                </ImageView>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/IVimage5"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="125dp"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/e"
                    android:tag="e" >
                </ImageView>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/IVimage6"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="125dp"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/f"
                    android:tag="f" >
                </ImageView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView2"
            android:layout_width="500dp"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/horizontalScrollView2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcherwrweq" >
        </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**list_item.xml(for ListView) -**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:singleLine="true"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for an answer to this, I had a slightly different implementation. I extended the ScrollView class and implemented onTouchListener in the child, and set it to self in the constructor.

In the onTouch callback, if the motion event object came with a value for pointer count as 2, I returned true, otherwise false. This way, if two fingers were moving on screen, it would consider it as a pinch to zoom, otherwise would consider it as normal scroll. I didn't request for parent touch disable etc.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    if(motionEvent.getPointerCount() == 2){
        mCallbacks.onPinchZoomAction(motionEvent);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Its not only that Google says its bad practice, it just doesnt make much sense. Supose you have two vertical scrollable views nested one inside the other. When you move you finger over the scroll views, which one do you want to move, the inner or the outer one?

You should rethink your UI desing to something that does not require this, there a many ways to make a great UI and still keep it really simple.

Comment: I don't see the point. That's exactly as a scrollable code snippet inside this scrollable Stackoverflow window. You scroll the Stackoverflow window (= your browser window) until the mouse pointer falls inside the code snippet area. Then you start scrolling the code snippet.

Comment: Apps are not web pages. Something that makes sense in one enviornment doesnt need to make sense in another one.

Comment: Sometimes you have small elements that use scrollviews, but then everything else is also inside a scrollview. I have that situation right now and it makes absolute sense to have a scrollview functioning inside another scrollview.

Comment: So what is the solution for holding a scrollview within scrollview vertically.. as webpages support it. Pls provide me a valid solution.        Thanks in Advance

Comment: Also I have tried the above solutions. Nothing works out well