# Android UI: scrolling horizontal and vertical in coordination with top and lateral menu

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to find a solution similar to this one but for an Android platform:

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/hipmunk-flight-search/id419950680?mt=8

Have a look at that website. Basically the idea is to scroll laterally and vertically on the green content area (see the image below) and the two menus (red and blu) should scroll accordingly. If you scroll over the content area (green) left-right, the blu top menu should scroll as well. If you scroll up-down the red menu should scroll up-down as well.

The areas of the menu, is always there in the page.

[image]

does anyone have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591083/android-synchronized-scrolling-of-two-different-views)

that guy Pedro Loureiro explain it shortly although providing no extremely detailed source code. But that's how I sorted it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to put a Scrollview inside of a Horizontal Scrollview. Hope You can scroll in both direction.

Comment: It is more complicated than this. You need to be able to scroll the same rows on the green and red areas and at the same time the same columns on the blue and the green areas