# How to add footer view to android webview?

Tags: android, webview, scrollview

I want to scroll webview together with another view as if they were in single scroll container. How can I do that?

Please, do not suggest that I place both in ScrollView - 1 scroll container inside another scroll container is incorrect for android.

Comment: it's not really clear, what you need?
you can put webview and the other view in linear layout, vertical, and put the linear in scrollView

Comment: You could post a visual representation of what you want because it's not yet clear what you want to accomplish.

Comment: You should refer to this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591083/android-synchronized-scrolling-of-two-different-views

Cheers,

Comment: WebView is scroll container by itself. It means, it can scroll html you put in it. What I want is "attach" one more native android view to this scroll container. How can I achieve such effect?

Comment: you want to append another View inside the webView?

Comment: I want to archive the effect that another view scrolls together with webview contents. It works like webview footer. It works exactly as if you put webview + 1 more view inside scrollview.