# In Android, how can I create a spreadsheet type of view

Tags: android, listview, horizontalscrollview

I have a need to create a view that is 14 columns wide by unlimited columns high.  A horizontal scroll view within a list view would be perfect, but all the comments say to never do this.  I tried anyway and it never worked properly.

Can anyone show me a way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read this question/answer:

[ScrollView Inside ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490821/scrollview-inside-scrollview/4492050#4492050)

it includes both a warning about the risks that you are taking and a solution if you decide to cope with them!

I've solved this problem (without incurring in the possible problems) by implementing a custom view.