# Multiple Scrollable TextViews inside a ScrollView

Tags: android, textview, scrollview

I have a `ScrollView` that contains a complex `LinearLayout` with various elements, among which there are several `TextView` with maxHeight defined and a long text inside. I need to enable scrolling the text inside the `TextView` when touch-and-dragging inside it, and the normal scroll of the `ScrollView` when touch-and-drag outside of them.

Is there a proper and elegant way to do this - if at all possible - or do I have to get dirty and start overriding the `onTouchEvent` handlers on all elements involved?

UPD 1: Judging from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490821/scrollview-inside-scrollview) there is no elegant solution, and the UI will have to be rethinked to include only one layer of scrollable elements.

Comment: do you have a fix number of textviews or is it dynamic?

Comment: Just 2. For now. Might be more in the future, but the layout is static, if that's the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So it's not pretty, but you can extend from TextView and block the scrollview from scrolling. It's not as nice unless your textviews are large enough. After using this solution we found that it is best if you have a "show more" label that the users can click to show the full thing. Anyway, extend from TextView and override the onTouchEvent method:

```
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
      this.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    }
    if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
      this.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
  }
```

Comment: As you said, it's not pretty, but there seems to be no other way. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

A ScrollView is a FrameLayout, meaning you should place one child in it containing the entire contents to scroll; this child may itself be a layout manager with a complex hierarchy of objects. A child that is often used is a LinearLayout in a vertical orientation, presenting a vertical array of top-level items that the user can scroll through.

```
 <ScrollView   
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"  
  android:layout_height="150px"   
  android:layout_width="fill_parent">  

   <TextView   
   android:id="@+id/TEXT_VIEW"   
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
   android:text="This text view should act as header This text view should act as header This text view should act as header This text view should act as header This text view should act as header This text view should act as header This text view should act as header" />  
 </ScrollView>
```

Comment: I know that. My `ScrollView` has a `LinearLayout` as child, and the `TextView`s I'm talking about go inside the `LinearLayout`. But I can't get them to have their own scrolling, the `ScrollView`'s scroll takes over. I thought there might be a property of some sort that causes the child's scroll handling to take precedence over the parent's one.

Answer (score 0):

you can see the APIdemos for more information, there is a a view of lot of text's with their own stylized scrollview in the same windows. For more inforation you can visit:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/index.html

Comment: The only thing I could find in the API demos is a `ScrollView` having `LinearLayout`s added dynamically. It has nothing (that I could see) related to `TextView` nested inside a `ScrollView`.