# HorizontalScrollView inside ListView

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a horizontal scroll view inside a ListView. I have the ListView working, but putting data inside the horizontalscrollview(HSV) is not working out for me. Please advise! (I coded the listview, tested and now trying to add a horizontalscrollview)

The HSV is going to be for every listitem.

So basically for my logic on how I am approaching this: I have my listview adapter, i decided to place the HSV inside the adapter so it loops through each listItem and places a HSV inside that.

My Xml lookis like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


        <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtProjectName" />

        <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtProjectDescription" />

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout 
                android:id="@+id/projectTasks"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/txtProjectTasks" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then I created a custom adapter to run through all the projects.

```
public class ProjectListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Projects> {

int resource;
String response;
Context context;
ArrayList<Tasks> taskArray = null;

// Initialize adapter
public ProjectListAdapter(Context context, int resource,
        List<Projects> items) {
    super(context, resource, items);
    this.resource = resource;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LinearLayout projectView;

    // Get the current project object
    Projects project = getItem(position);
    //
    // Inflate the view
    if (convertView == null) {
        projectView = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        String inflater = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(inflater);
        vi.inflate(resource, projectView, true);
    } else {
        projectView = (LinearLayout) convertView;
    }

    TextView PROJECT_NAME = (TextView) projectView
            .findViewById(R.id.txtProjectName);
    TextView PROJECT_DESCRIPTION = (TextView) projectView
            .findViewById(R.id.txtProjectDescription);

    PROJECT_NAME.setText(project.getNAME());
    PROJECT_DESCRIPTION.setText(project.getDESCRIPTION());
    taskArray = new ArrayList<Tasks>();
    taskArray = (ArrayList<Tasks>) project.getTasks();

    for (Tasks tasks : taskArray) {
        HorizontalScrollView TASKS = (HorizontalScrollView) projectView
                .findViewById(R.id.projectTasks);
        LinearLayout taskLayout = (LinearLayout) projectView
                .findViewById(R.id.projectTasks);
        TextView taskTxt = (TextView) projectView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtProjectTasks);
        taskTxt.setText(tasks.getTASK_ID());
        taskLayout.addView(taskTxt);

    }
    return projectView;
}
```

}

That last bit of code is where the adapter will loop through to make the HSV, but something isn't working how I would like, please please help!

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/4492050/1705641.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow following link to have HSV in ListView:
http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34

OR

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    boolean handled = mGesture.onTouchEvent(event);
    return handled;
}
Then, add the following code which will decide to steal the event from the item children and give it to our onTouchEvent, or let it be handled by them.

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    switch( ev.getActionMasked() ){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
             mInitialX = ev.getX();
             mInitialY = ev.getY();             
             return false;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
             float deltaX = Math.abs(ev.getX() - mInitialX);
             float deltaY = Math.abs(ev.getY() - mInitialY);
             return ( deltaX > 5 || deltaY > 5 );
        default:
             return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
Finally, don't forget to declare the variables in your class:

private float mInitialX;
private float mInitialY;
```

Source: [Horizontal ListView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240331/horizontal-listview-in-android)

Comment: Hey thanks, ill look into this.  I'm trying to have a List of horizontalscrollviews. Is that possible with this?

Comment: you mean to say each item in ListView as HSV? I dnt think its possible with above code. Try above code and let me know what issues you face...

Comment: yes thats exactly what I am trying to do. Checkout the pulse news app for android. Thats similar to what i am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

In your code this line is not ok, you're creating a new linearLayout but it's not from your custom view:

```
projectView = new LinearLayout(getContext());
```

So try this:

```
View projectView = convertView;

// Inflate the view
if (projectView == null) {
    String inflater = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
    LayoutInflater vi;
    vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(inflater);
    projectView = vi.inflate(resource, false);
}
```

And define your projectView as a View, not a LinearLayout.

Comment: i made those changes, and tested it out without the HSV and the code does work, however the HSV stuff does not work. I believe I am not inflating it correctly. Could you advise?

Comment: Ok, probably it's not about inflating if you did what i told... But i could be your listView getting touch event and so your HSV couldn't get it. You may need to handle with touch events.

Comment: My HSV only has one TextView in its layout, but when the HSV gets populated it will have multiple TextView per HSV.