# How to intercept only motion event from scrollview with a specific angle?

Tags: java, android

I tried wihout success to disable a vertical ScrollView for a specific angle.

The goal behind this is to handle properly multiple horizontal ListView nested in a vertical ScrollView.

I tried this but it's not working :

```
public class VScrollView extends ScrollView {

    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
    View.OnTouchListener mGestureListener;

    public VScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new YScrollDetector());
        setFadingEdgeLength(0);
    }

    public VScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new YScrollDetector());
        setFadingEdgeLength(0);
    }

    public VScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new YScrollDetector());
        setFadingEdgeLength(0);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev) && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }


    class YScrollDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
            if (e1 != null && e2 != null) {
                double delta_x = (e1.getX() - e2.getX());
                double delta_y = (e1.getY() - e2.getY());
                double radians = Math.abs(Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x)));
                if (radians > 80 && radians < 100) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that's probably what you don't want to hear, but Google keep asking us not doing that.

Refer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4492050/62921) which basically quote Google saying

> You should never use a HorizontalScrollView with a ListView [...]