# How to develop ListView within ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview, custom-lists

Friends,

I am trying to develop an application which requires the below UI:

[image]

I know its not a feasible thing to run a `ListView` with-in `ListView` or with-in a `ScrollView`. So I'll like to know that **Is there any other way to do this same thing ?** as the UI has to be same as its running in its LIVE iOS App.

Thanks in advance.

---

*Solution:* Thanks guys for all of your answers, but as I told that the [Expandable-ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) is not the option in my condition. So I have creating a dynamic layout in Java Class file using an amount of various **Layouts & Widget**'s Array. It took a lot of practice but it covered the necessity.

Comment: [Expandable List View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

Comment: [android-expandable-listview-simple](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/07/android-expandable-listview-simple.html) > check this it will help you

Comment: Never even think of putting a **scrollable** view inside another **scrollable** *view*, Use `ExpandableListView`

Answer (score 1):

You don't really describe your problem in detail but from your indication of a blue bar at the left, I suppose that you want to have some sort of a secondary ScrollView inside the primary ListView; which itself has its one scrolling view. If so, then using an ExpdandableListView will not be the solution that you want.

Android has some difficulties managing a ScrollView inside another ScrollView but if this is what you want, then take a look at:  [ScrollView Inside ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490821/scrollview-inside-scrollview) .

Be warned that these solutions are not perfect and that probably you will never achieve the same level of control for this type of thing on Android as you can have on iOS.