# Android Multi ScrollView Issue

Tags: android, layout, scrollview

My Layout is like this :

```
<SrollViewA>
    <LayoutA>
    </LayoutA>
    <LayoutB>
      <ScrollViewB>
          <TextView>
          </textView>
      </ScrollViewB>
   </LayoutB>
</ScrollViewA>
```

When i run my app, only the SrollViewA is working but when i try my app without the ScrollViewA, the ScrollViewB is perfectly Working.

Any clues what i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you take a look here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490821/scrollview-inside-scrollview

Comment: See this ! http://stackoverflow.com/a/4492050/567245

Comment: you cannnot create nested scroll view, only top scrollview will work, to keep scrollB working in that scenario override onTouchEvent of ScrollView and onTouch of ScrollB disable scrollA then it should work and on up event enable scrollA scrolling.