# how to scroll pull to refresh scrollview in normal scrollview

Tags: android, layout, refresh, scrollview, pull

Here is my layout xml.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/garae_scroll"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/background"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false" >
   <RelativeLayout>
      ...
      <com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshScrollView>
         <LinearLayout/>
      </com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshScrollView>
   </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I already tried the solution in this link:
[ScrollView Inside ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490821/scrollview-inside-scrollview)

However, it didn't work.  How can do use child PullToRefreshScrollView??
Please help me.

Answer (score 10):

If I understand your question, you want to implement a Pull to refresh in your Scrollview. Instead, to use the library you are using, I would suggest you to implement a SwipeRefreshLayout 
        https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html
It is a layout that implements a pull-to-refresh like in the application of Google+ or Gmail.

Here's an example implementing `SwipeRefreshLayout` in your xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

          <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:id="@+id/garae_scroll"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

         </ScrollView>

       </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

**NOTE**

It is **highly not recommended** to put a Scrollview/Listview inside a Scrollview/Listview. The first reason is about the performance and Romain Guy explains that in one video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Comment: Thanks Hugo I checked so much example but none mentioned that we need to implement on query listener.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/swipe/add-swipe-interface