# Create a RelativeLayout dynamically and positioning views inside

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I would like to create a method which returns a `RelativeLayout` created dynamically. To be clear, let's use this simplified example:

```
private RelativeLayout createLayout() {
        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(activity);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        layout.setLayoutParams(params);

        TextView tv1 = new TextView(activity);
        tv1.setText("Text 1");

        TextView tv2 = new TextView(activity);
        tv2.setText("Text 2");

        TextView tv3 = new TextView(activity);
        tv3.setText("Text 3");

        layout.addView(tv1);
        layout.addView(tv2);
        layout.addView(tv3);

        return layout;
}
```

Now I want to position these `TextView`s relatively to each other. For that I have the idea to use a `LayoutParams` with the `addRule` method.

But this method requires an ID, e.g. `addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, tv2Id)`. It means that I have to set an ID for each `TextView`s.

My problem is that the createLayout method will be called several times, so the question is:

Do I have to set different IDs for the `TextView`s each time the method is called in order to avoid conflicts ? If so, how can I do that ?

Most generally, Is there a better solution for doing it ?

---

**EDIT**

The idea behind this is to have a kind of `ListView`, where each item contains a `Map` (that can be shown or hidden).

Problem: the Map can't be scroll if it is inside a `ListView` (at least I did not manage to do that).

For that, I have decided to use a `ScrollView` and a `LinearLayout` to copy the behaviour of a `ListView`. This way the `Map` can be scrolled correctly and now, all I have to do is to create the items dynamically

Comment: The question is: why do you want to use this? Is it part of a list? Then listview would be a better solution.

Comment: you. can use same IDs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID's don't have to be unique. As you can see from this [extract](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setId%28int%29)

> **setId (int id)**
>
> Sets the identifier for this view. The identifier does not have to be unique in this view's hierarchy. The identifier should be a positive number.

But like you said, if you want to avoid conflict then you have to find a way to generate unique identifiers for each view.

Frankly, IMO I don't think it matters much the value of the ID. You can use 10, 20, 30. Just make sure you can have access to them anytime you need it, possible using a `static final` variable.

You asked if there is a better solution, yes there is. The most preferred way is to inflate an xml layout.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your explanation. I will try to use a XML layout and to inflate it.

Comment: @G.T. A scrollable item inside a listview is a bad idea and bad practice. I would advise you make the item static but onclick, you pop up a dialog and the scrolling is done on this dialog.

Comment: Is this a bad practice for the user experience or for the performance of the application?

Comment: @G.T. Nested Scrollable views is bad for app performance. Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490821/scrollview-inside-scrollview