# Android : scrolling together view pager in scrollview

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-scrollview

My App's layout as follow.

```
<ScrollView> // (A)
    <View1> // (B)
    <View2> // (C)
    <ViewPager />
</ScrollView>
```

In `ViewPager`, each fragment has `ScrollView`(D).

In Scrolling, I want to be scrolled (A) and (D) together, but not working(only scrolled (D)).

Finally, I want to be scrolled to (C) in scrolling (D).
((C) is visible and fixed, (B) is not).

Comment: too many A,B,C,D,.. ;) . I know that you can't use scrollView inside another scrollView.but by some code you can make parallel scrolling

Comment: You should have a look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490821/scrollview-inside-scrollview