# RecyclerView with Scrollable CardView

Tags: android, scrollview, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

**What I'd like to do**

---

I've got a `RecyclerView` with different `CardView`'s inside. For that I wrote a `RecycleView.Adapter` with a `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`. Which works perfectly fine.

Now I'd like to have cards which host a `ScrollView`. My `Layout` for that looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_assignment_comments_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Kommentare"
        android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_large_material" />


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_assignment_comments_title"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_comments_card_holder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

So far so good. The Card gets displayed *but I can't scroll the content inside the ScrollView only the RecyclerView itself.*

How can I make my ScrollView scrollable inside the RecyclerView? Can someone show me the magic?

Comment: asked many times, google for: android scrollable inside scrollable ... there is no good way for doing this ...

Comment: @Selvin I'm not sure if this is the same problematic - but however thank you

Comment: first link is *ListView inside ScrollView is not scrolling on Android* ... this is exactly the same problem ...

Comment: @Selvin However is a ListView != RecyclerView but I'll check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could solve the problem by adding following to my `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`:

```
mCommentsHolder.mCommentsScrollContainer.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Now it works perfectly smooth. I've got that from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11554823/909003).