# Two nested vertical scroll views in android

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I am using two vertical scroll views(say,parent and child).what is the issue is I am not able to scroll my child view instead it scrolls my whole parent view,is there any way that I can restrict my parent view to scroll when I scroll my child scroll view and vice versa?

need help...thanks in advance..!!

Comment: Follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490821/scrollview-inside-scrollview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to handle the touch event to do this effectively

```
        outerScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                findViewById(R.id.inner_scroll).getParent()
                        .requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                return false;
            }
        });

        innerScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: " findViewById(R.id.inner_scroll).getParent()" means "parentScrollView"

Answer (score 1):

**Try this one**

Note: Here parentScrollView means Outer ScrollView And childScrollView means Innner ScrollView

```
parentScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.v(TAG, "PARENT TOUCH");

        findViewById(R.id.child_scroll).getParent()
                .requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
        return false;
    }
});

childScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.v(TAG, "CHILD TOUCH");

        // Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of  child view
        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

-Here is the SOlution you can find With the description[Here.](http://technet.weblineindia.com/mobile/handle-scrollable-views-or-controls-in-another-scrollview-in-android/)

```
    m_parentScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() 
    {
           public boolean onTouch(View p_v, MotionEvent p_event) 
            {
                   m_childScrollView.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
               //  We will have to follow above for all scrollable contents
               return false;
            }
    });


m_childScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() 
{
      public boolean onTouch(View p_v, MotionEvent p_event)
       {
          // this will disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of child view
           p_v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
           return false;
       }
});
```

//  We will have to follow above for all child scrollable contents
I

These two methods can solve your answer.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @BrianWhite THanks for your suggestion and yes you are right at your point.