# the scrollView not working in fragment android

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I developed an android application in which the scroll-view is not scrolling.. I am posting the code here please check and if found any error please help.. Here I used ScrollView as root and then LinearLayout... but this is not scrolling up.. I Updated the xml still not working

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center|top"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:weightSum="1">

 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/arrowImageView"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_grey"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/NameTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="-"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="-"
    android:textSize="15dp"

    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/positionTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="-"
    android:textSize="15dp"

    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/IdTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/label_id"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

<!--items-->

<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/takeoff_color"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
         />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/label_b"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/image1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/image2"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:src="@drawable/document"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/label_date"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/image2"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/DateTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/image3"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:src="@drawable/document_color"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/label_end_of"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/image3"

        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/endOfTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"

        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_money"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/label_c"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/currentSalaryTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:src="@drawable/bag_color"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/label_h_total"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/salaryTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"

        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"

    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:src="@drawable/purchase_order"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/label_g"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"

        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

EDITED AS BELOW, but still not working well, the scrollbar stop at half of label name:"label_h_total"

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center|top"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
>

 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/arrowImageView"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_grey"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/NameTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="-"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="-"
    android:textSize="15dp"

    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/positionTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="-"
    android:textSize="15dp"

    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/IdTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/label_id"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

<!--items-->

<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/takeoff_color"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
         />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/label_b"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/image1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/image2"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:src="@drawable/document"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/label_date"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/image2"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/DateTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/image3"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:src="@drawable/document_color"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/label_end_of"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/image3"

        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/endOfTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"

        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_money"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/label_c"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/currentSalaryTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:src="@drawable/bag_color"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/label_h_total"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/salaryTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"

        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"

    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:src="@drawable/purchase_order"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/label_g"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"

        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: There are 2 ScrollViews or nested ScrollViews ?

Comment: yes 2, just for trying to work

Comment: you put <!--items-->
there are some views or not if not then you opened two scroll views and close one.
And scrollView can have only 1 child so be carefull to resolve this

Comment: Please add these two lines in your code first    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

Comment: Just go through this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490821/scrollview-inside-scrollview/13634181#13634181)

Comment: i updated the xml, but still not woking

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center|top"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:weightSum="1">

xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" put this in scrollview and edit child of scrollview.
```

Comment: no i closed two see "    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>"

Comment: i updated the xml with one ScrollView, but still not woking

Answer (score 0):

The Warning
A scrolling widget such as a ScrollView should not contain any nested scrolling widgets since this has various usability issues

Answer (score 0):

This should be works. There was a problem with the LinearLayout, the height was wrap_content. The first child of scrollview needs to have only match_parent for both width and height and that's it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/arrowImageView"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_grey"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/NameTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="-"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="-"
            android:textSize="15dp"

            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/positionTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="-"
            android:textSize="15dp"

            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/IdTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/label_id"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <!--items-->

        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/image1"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/takeoff_color"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/label_b"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/image1"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="-"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/image2"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:src="@drawable/document"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/label_date"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/image2"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/DateTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="-"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/image3"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:src="@drawable/document_color"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/label_end_of"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/image3"

                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/endOfTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="-"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"

                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_money"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/label_c"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/currentSalaryTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="-"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:src="@drawable/bag_color"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/label_h_total"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/salaryTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="-"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"

                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"

            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:src="@drawable/purchase_order"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/label_g"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="-"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"

                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: the scrollbar end at half on the "label_h_total", why?