# ScrollView in both directions android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout with scrollview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    >
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:background="@color/antiquewhite">
        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_layou"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_weight="15"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="@color/bisque">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="@string/user_information_text"
            android:textSize="26dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subtitle_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/user_information_subtitle_text" 
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" 
            android:textColor="@color/black"/>

    </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/body_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="85" 
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:weightSum="100"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/left_part"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" 
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:weightSum="100"
                android:background="@color/antiquewhiter">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/first_name_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:text="@string/first_name_text"
                    style="@style/bold_text18"
                    />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/first_name_edit_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:weightSum="100">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/first_name_edit_text"
            style="@style/editTextsvCard"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="90"
            android:ems="10"


            >

        </EditText>

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/company_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:text="@string/company_text"
                    style="@style/bold_text18" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/company_edit_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:weightSum="100">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/company_edit_text"
            style="@style/editTextsvCard"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="90"
            android:ems="10"
             >

        </EditText>

                </LinearLayout>
                               <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/phone_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:text="@string/phone_text"
                    style="@style/bold_text18"/>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/phone_edit_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:weightSum="100">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/phone_edit_text"
            style="@style/editTextsvCard"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="90"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="phone"
            >

        </EditText>

                </LinearLayout> 

                           <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/e_mail_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:text="@string/e_mail_text"
                    style="@style/bold_text18" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/e_mail_edit_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:weightSum="100">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/e_mail_edit_text"
            style="@style/editTextsvCard"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="90"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            >

        </EditText>

                </LinearLayout>

                             <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mobile_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:text="@string/mobile_text"
                    style="@style/bold_text18"/>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/mobile_edit_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:weightSum="100">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mobile_edit_text"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            style="@style/editTextsvCard"
            android:layout_weight="90"
            android:ems="10"

             >

        </EditText>

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/right_part"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:paddingRight="40dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" 
                android:weightSum="100"
                android:background="@color/antiquewhiter">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/last_name_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:text="@string/last_name_text"
                    style="@style/bold_text18" />
                   <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/last_name_edit_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:weightSum="100">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/last_name_edit_text"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="100"
            android:ems="10"
            style="@style/editTextsvCard"
            >

        </EditText>

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/position_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:text="@string/position_text"
                    style="@style/bold_text18"/>
                   <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/position_edit_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:weightSum="100">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/position_edit_text"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="100"
            android:ems="10"
            style="@style/editTextsvCard"
           >

        </EditText>

                </LinearLayout>

                   <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fax_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:text="@string/fax_text"
                    style="@style/bold_text18"/>
                   <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/fax_edit_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:weightSum="100">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/fax_edit_text"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="100"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="phone"
            style="@style/editTextsvCard"
             >

        </EditText>

                </LinearLayout>

                   <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/internet_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:text="@string/internet_text"
                    style="@style/bold_text18"/>
                   <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/internet_edit_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:weightSum="100">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/internet_edit_text"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="100"
            android:ems="10"
            style="@style/editTextsvCard"
             >

        </EditText>

                </LinearLayout>
                                   <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/b_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:text="@string/internet_text"
                    style="@style/bold_text18"
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    />

                   <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/button_edit_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:weightSum="100"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:gravity="right">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/speichern_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:layout_weight="40"
            android:text="@string/speichern_text"
            >


        </Button>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Vertical view work perfect but I would like to know if I can add horizontal scroll to this layout because when I have horizontal orientation layout looks good but when I change orientation I don't want to reduce size some elements in layout. I think about add horizontal scrool. This is possible?

Comment: A solution with Appbarlayout in a CoordinatorLayout: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399605/how-can-i-make-my-layout-scroll-both-horizontally-and-vertically/78001428#78001428

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I add:

```
<HorizontalScrollView 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
>
```

as child my scroll view and this solution works great.

Comment: It works, but only one of the ScrollView operates in the same time. I mean you can't scroll diagonally.