# Draw a large table and scroll it smoothly

Tags: android, scroll, scrollview

I have a table about 20 columns and 200 rows, which can not display only in one screen. I have to scroll it both horizontally and vertically, so is there any way to achieve it?

I have tried TableLayout and it can do such things but it's bad to scroll. The database browser in Re Explorer is perfect, how can I get to this?

Comment: Post your adapter code and we can give you tips to optimise

Comment: @Rawkode I just wrap TableLayout in ScrollView and HorizontalScrollView

Answer (score 0):

You may found your solution/work around with some of these

http://blog.gorges.us/2010/06/android-two-dimensional-scrollview/

[How can I make my layout scroll both horizontally and vertically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399605/problem-in-horizontal-scroll-in-android)

But, If you are not forced to use the same Layout Design by your employer, Then PLEASE Change the design of the screen.. because the current design you choose is NOT SUPPORTED BY ANDROID that is a kind of web or desktop screen design.