# Scrolling LinearLayout(Created in Java not in XML) Horizontally and Vertically

Tags: java, android, android-layout, scrollview

I want to Scroll linear layout (created in java file using `LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this)`) vertically and also horizontally. `ScrollView` allows only vertical scrolling `HorizontalScrollView` allows only horizontal scrolling, But I want both functionality to my `LinearLayout`.

I haven't got any solution for my question. Many people saying that we can get two dimensional scrolling my embedding HorizontalScrollView inside ScrollView, But this is not giving a good scrolling effect. How ever many sources tells that the only solution for this question is the link(http://blog.gorges.us/2010/06/android-two-dimensional-scrollview). However this link is no longer active. Please help me.

Comment: Enable Horizontal and vertical scrolling for ScrollView

Comment: Check the accepted answer at [how-can-i-make-my-layout-scroll-both-horizontally-and-vertically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399605/how-can-i-make-my-layout-scroll-both-horizontally-and-vertically).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, it may help you..

```
    ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(this);
    HorizontalScrollView horizontalScrollView = new HorizontalScrollView(this);
    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

    horizontalScrollView.addView(linearLayout);

    scrollView.addView(horizontalScrollView);

    setContentView(scrollView);
```

Comment: Mr.Anil Kumar It is working fine but by default layout is moving to complete right side, Even If I try to enter any input the same problem.

Comment: check the orientations properly, some where it might be set to right

Comment: This method doestn't provide a user friendly experience. I need a better idea for a better user experience