# Scroll listview vertical and horizontal same image

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I want design layout same like my attached image, this listview can horizontal and vertical scroll. I create header A B C by gridview, but not add list view in the rest.

Image:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand clearly your issue: can you explain a little more  what do you expect, what did you try and what is the behaviour now?

Comment: i want create demo UI same image attach, i used scrollview, gridview and listview, but i create header (A B C  like image) by gridview, part "content A"... i create by listview, but i not join them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you try to put above a `ListView`, a `ScrollView` or a `GridView` **another** `GridView` as an `HeaderView` which this scrolls horizontally. It seems like adding several widgets which have their own handling of scroll event.. Don't know if this is possible.

Try another way, change your `GridView` as a `HorizontalScrollView` and put your views A, B, C.. inside.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

        Here, your views A, B, C...

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

See an example of this simple layout: [Scrollabale listview in both direction with header using Horizontal scrollview](http://pankajkakade101.wordpress.com/2013/12/20/scrollabale-listview-in-both-direction-with-header-using-horizontal-scrollview/).

Then if you want to scroll the content but keep the header part fixed, try to add this layout above your content with a `ViewGroup` container (inside LinearLayout, RelativeLayout or something else) with an include:

```
<RelativeLayout
    ... >
    <include 
        android:layout="@layout/layout_horizontal_scrollview"
        ... >
    <ListView
        ... >
</RelativeLayout>
```

This should do the trick..

But if you want that your header part scroll at the sime time to your content, try to add this layout as a `HeaderView` *(I've just try this, it works)*:

1. Create an `HorizontalScrollView` for header:

   ```
   <HorizontalScrollView
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:orientation="horizontal" >
       Here, your views A, B, C...
   </HorizontalScrollView>
   ```
2. Inflate this layout as a `HeaderView`:

   ```
   View header = View.inflate(this, R.layout.layout_horizontal_scrollview, null);
   listview.addHeaderView(header);
   ```

*Note: add a `HeaderView` to a GridView isn't possible, you could do this with a special adapter (like [HFGridView](https://github.com/SergeyBurish/HFGridView)).*

Comment: This works, just tried it! The headerview has a horizontal scroll whereas your list has a vertical scroll and your header scroll with the content. You inflate the HorizontalScrollView with addHeaderView and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Compose them (`GridView` and `ListView`) in `RelativeLayout` or vertical oriented `LinearLayout`this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/gridview" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

Item to ListView is added programmatically by setting data to adapter.

**Edit** (enabling vertical and horizontal scroll):
Try this [How can I make my layout scroll both horizontally and vertically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399605/how-can-i-make-my-layout-scroll-both-horizontally-and-vertically#answer-1409629).

Comment: But not vertical scroll and horizontal scroll

Comment: You mean you want to scroll them simultaneously?

Comment: Your views within layout within `HorizontalScrollView` within `ScrollView` is the answer. Check edit above.

Comment: @ghoshak OP's wanted a scrolling header not the content scrollable. This is not a good practice like you can read on comments above your links: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4492050/2668136

Comment: @user3401211 In the case you want only scrolling (in both directions) header without scrolling content below it you could wrap only GridView in HorizontalScrollView and ScrollView. As I get GridView is header and ListView is content for you.