# Recycler View Scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Is there a way that I could scroll a row vertically and horizontally in a RecyclerView.

I use this code but I only scroll vertically.

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
```

Answer (score 0):

FOR VERTICAL

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
            = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    RecyclerView rvUsers = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvUsers);
    rvUsers.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

FOR HORIZONTAL

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
                = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        RecyclerView rvUsers = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvUsers);
        rvUsers.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Comment: Hi, @Naveen. Is there way that I can scroll the row vertically and horizontally?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399605/how-can-i-make-my-layout-scroll-both-horizontally-and-vertically