# Scrolling a ListView in both direction

Tags: android, xml, listview

I have created a ListView and it has so many child elements. That's why, its not showing fully & properly. is there any way to enable scrolling vertically and horizontally in ListView?

Here's my listview.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lvserial"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:text="Serial"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lvmloCode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:text="MLO CODE"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lvlineNo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:text="Line No"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lvcontainerNo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:text="Container No"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lvcontainerDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:text="Container Description"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lvcontainerType"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:text="Container Type"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lvtareWeight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:text="Tare Weight"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lvgrossWeight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:text="Gross Weight"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lvcontainerSealNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:text="Container Serial Number"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lvdepuCode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:text="Depu Code"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lvcommodityList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:text="Commodity List"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make my layout scroll both horizontally and vertically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399605/how-can-i-make-my-layout-scroll-both-horizontally-and-vertically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/hor_scroll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lvserial"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:text="Serial"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lvmloCode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:text="MLO CODE"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lvlineNo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:text="Line No"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lvcontainerNo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:text="Container No"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lvcontainerDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:text="Container Description"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lvcontainerType"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:text="Container Type"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lvtareWeight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:text="Tare Weight"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lvgrossWeight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:text="Gross Weight"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lvcontainerSealNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:text="Container Serial Number"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lvdepuCode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:text="Depu Code"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lvcommodityList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:text="Commodity List"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot :) Now okay :)