# Navigateable coordinate view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

My goal is to create a view larger than the devices screen that the user can navigate in, and where i can position imageview based on a coordinate:

[image]

I have tried creating a layout within a `HorizontalScrollView` and `VerticalScrollView`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399605/how-can-i-make-my-layout-scroll-both-horizontally-and-vertically):

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="320px" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/linlay" android:layout_width="320px"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:stretchColumns="1"
            android:background="#000000"/>

    </HorizontalScrollView>

</ScrollView>
```

The problem with that is that it only allows scrolling in 1 direction at the time.

Is there are way to obtain free movement on all axes and have the view in a coordinate system so that other views can be placed on or off the screen ?

Comment: try to check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398057/android-move-a-view-on-touch-move-action-move